# Query tune with large data

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need help with a query that is very slow.

My data models:

- 2379k categories (node)
- 1746315k users (node)
- 376900k products (node)
- 40m views (client -> view (date) -> product) (edge)
- 2m belong (product -> belong -> category) (edge)

I have created the following indices:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (product: Product) ASSERT product.idProduct IS UNIQUE;
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (customer: Customer) ASSERT customer.idCustomer IS UNIQUE;
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (category: Category) ASSERT category.idCategory IS UNIQUE;
```

I want to display recommendations from "Who view also view":

I have two basic queries, one with category filter and one without.

Query without filter:

```
MATCH (p:Product {idProduct: "178293"})<-[:VIEW]-(c:Customer)-[:VIEW]->(rec:Product)
WHERE not (rec.idProduct = "178293") 
WITH rec.idProduct AS recommendation, count(*) as views
ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 25
RETURN recommendation, views;
```

It's taking about 10 seconds to run.

Query with filter:

```
MATCH (p:Product {idProduct: "178293"})<-[:VIEW]-(c:Customer)-[:VIEW]->(rec:Product)-[BELONG]->(ca:Category {idCategory: "173"})
WHERE not (rec.idProduct = "178293") 
WITH rec.idProduct AS recommendation, count(*) as views
ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 25
RETURN recommendation, views;
```

It's taking about 60 seconds to run.

I would like to receive some tips to tune this query.

Im using neo4j 3.3.3 community edition.

My computer is an I7, with 8GB ram, ssd and running ubuntu 14.04

The queries were executed in the browser.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the Cypher planner two [index hints](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/query-tuning/using/#query-using-index-hint), so that it is encouraged to use both indexes. By default, your planner may only be using one of the indexes.

```
MATCH (p:Product {idProduct: "178293"})<-[:VIEW]-(c:Customer)-[:VIEW]->(rec:Product)-[BELONG]->(ca:Category {idCategory: "173"})
USING INDEX p:Product(idProduct)
USING INDEX ca:Category(idCategory)
WHERE NOT (rec.idProduct = "178293")
WITH rec.idProduct AS recommendation, count(*) as views
ORDER BY views DESC
LIMIT 25
RETURN recommendation, views;
```

You can discover whether the planner generates a plan that uses both indexes by using the [PROFILE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/) operator.

By the way, your `WHERE NOT (rec.idProduct = "178293")` clause may not be necessary if a `Customer` node can only have a single `VIEW` relationship to a `Product` node (since a `MATCH` clause automatically filters out matches that have duplicate relationships). Or, if that `WHERE` test is needed, you can simplify it to `WHERE rec <> p`, since `Product`s have unique `idProduct` values.

Comment: Thank you @cybersam

Time has dropped to 20s.

It's still very slow.

Here is the profile of the query: https://ibb.co/eGvVxn

I'm going to try to run this process on another machine. One m4.xlarge of aws...